# get static int variable class name with typeid(*this).name for its own definition - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I need to get the class name inside of one of its methods I just call:

```
typeid(*this).name()
```

(then I split the result into tokens and get the class name)

Now I have to define a static member variable and need to get the class name for that.
But I`m not in a method!
So, I cannot use (*this).

Initially, I thought I could do something like:

```
#define INIT_STAT_VAR
   const char * cname = typeid(*this).name;
   int cname##::var = 1;
```

Any idea how I could get the class name for the static member variable definition?
( no, I cannot just write the name of the class directly for the definition  ;] )

thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a) what you are doing with the class name b) why you cannot hard code it? Also, are you aware that what you are doing is inherently non-portable?

Comment: a. I would like to print out the class name and Method name (__FUNCTION__) every time the method (which has the #define implemented) was called
b. I want to implement this in all code I do, and the code should only be integrated when I want it so. I would just put the #define symbol in the relevant methods.
c. mmm...doesn`t matter, its just for my internal work, the final code desn`t need to have that implemented.

Comment: uh, I wanted to write the predefind macro with the two underscores before and after FUNCTION in line one, but that was changed to (FUNCTION)

Comment: just so that you know, "typeid(*this).name()" does not just give you the name of the class the code is in; if the class is polymorphic, it gives you the actual runtime type of the object that the method is invoked on, which may be a subclass of the class the method is defined in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is directly possible to do what you want - as a static method doesn't get an object pointer it can't call `typeid` on it. You could create a temporary object in the static method and use that on typeid, but that pretty much goes against having it as a static method.

Another solution (if you can guarantee that at least 1 instance of the class is defined) would be to create a static member variable which you initialise once in the Constructor, and then access from a static method. It's a little hacky, but works:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {
    if (name == NULL) {
      const std::type_info& id = typeid(*this);
      name = new std::string(id.name());
    }
    // Normal object creation.
  }

  static std::string getName() { return *name; }

private:
  static std::string* name;
};

std::string* Foo::name = NULL;
```

Comment: thanks, that looks interesting, Dave. But unfortunately, if in the last lines code, there`s again the class name (Foo) then, I also could write directly the definition of my variable. Or don`t I understand correctly?

Comment: @sciloop: Yeah, it's necessary to allocate storage for the static member, don't think there's a way around that.

Comment: yeah, after quite some hours of investigation I see I have to type the name in, every time I have another class...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeid(ClassName).name()` ... but then you could also do simply `"ClassName"`.

Comment: do you mean with (ClassName) and "ClassName" the specific class name?

Comment: uh, but the point of my question was how to get that name by not typing it in ;]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__class__` macro, if your compiler supports it.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no such thing, here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28VS.80%29.aspx). I also couldn`t find that for the intel compiler. But maybe it will be part of c++x0 standard?

Comment: I thought it was under consideration, but there's no sign of it in the current draft. D'oh.